# How do I create a pop up menu with custom views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I want to create a dropdown menu like this:

[image: Dropdown Menu]

I tried using [this dropdown library](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) but it does not allow to add more views in the cells, just shows the strings. What are my options here? Is it possible to edit this library to allow additional fields in it? OR should I use something else? Thanks!

Comment: use [this](https://github.com/xiekw2010/DXPopover) library... You can customize your pop up view however you want...

Answer (score 0):

This library worked well for me..

https://github.com/xiekw2010/DXPopover

1) If your menu item is Dynamic..

The popover view in this library is having one `Tableview (Simple Tableview)`. To achieve what you want, you will have to create `CustomCell` & Change `simple Table view` with `Custom Cell Table View`..

2) If your menu is Static & you create is as a view then,

This library is also working with Custom View in Popup View. You can simply use that by both way..

i) XIB file 
ii) simple view in same View Controller ..